# How to add .htaccess file in your local host? means what should be writte in file?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

object not found & 404 error in localhost xampp? .htaccess file were missing

Comment: Wordpress can create the .htaccess automatically. No need to add it manually. Even if you delete it on purpose, you can re-create it by re-saving `Permalinks` (which is under Settings menu).

Comment: Thanks, the brother for this kind info but why am getting these two errors?

Comment: when you visit just `localhost` does your wordpress run?

Comment: upon my visiting, xampp shows both errors. object not found! and error 404

Answer (score 0):

Your wordpress installation must be in the root folder of `htdocs` or in a subfolder such as `blog`.

For example, if you install your WP in `blog` folder under `htdocs`, you can then access your website via `localhost/blog` URL

**EDIT:**

Please try saving this code as `.htaccess` file and put it in the /wordpress folder where your wp-config.php and index.php are located.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I was expecting the same, but there is no such subfolder...  wordpress folder in small letters and this folder contains all the files of wordpress.

Comment: @AmmarAwan can you please add a screenshot from your computer, which shows the content of your `htdocs` folder?

Comment: what happens when you access localhost/wordpress?

Comment: Can you show the browser's address bar please? I'm not sure if this is generated at localhost/wordpress or not

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nDSEKll here is also the address bar included

Comment: @AmmarAwan I edited my answer and added `.htaccess` code. Please try adding it to your wordpress folder.

Comment: Sure Sir, I ll try!

Comment: I have tried, but that errors still existing @ozgur

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rdjATYp here you can see the file

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, actually, Someone else has Installed xampp multiple times in different Local Disks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when multiple xampp is installed on your PC, that error occurs and it won't go easily unless you find the correct-one ht-docs in your local disk.
You better install xampp in your local disk C where your windows reside.